# Ruby multiline string like PHP nowdoc?

Tags: ruby

It is possible to have multiline string in Ruby like the PHP's nowdoc [1]

e.g.

```
puts '

\\foo

'
```

I want to output be the following which has no escape

```
\\foo
```

[1] Nowdocs are to single-quoted strings what heredocs are to double-quoted strings. A nowdoc is specified similarly to a heredoc, but no parsing is done inside a nowdoc.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc

Answer (score 4):

As described in the [literals documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Here+Documents), you just need to put single quotes around the heredoc identifier, like this:

```
puts <<'EOS'
#{variable}
\\escaped
EOS
```

Output:

```
#{variable}
\\escaped
```

Answer (score 1):

Put single quotes around the heredoc delimiter:

```
> tmp = "hi"
> s = <<'EOS'
' #{tmp}
' \\foo
' EOS
=> "\#{tmp}\n\\\\foo\n"
> puts s
#{tmp}
\\foo
```

Answer (score 0):

```
2.1.0 :001 > %q{
2.1.0 :002'> my
2.1.0 :003'> single
2.1.0 :004'> quoted
2.1.0 :005'> multiline
2.1.0 :006'> string
2.1.0 :007'> }
 => "\nmy\nsingle\nquoted\nmultiline\nstring\n" 

2.1.0 :008 > %Q{
2.1.0 :009"> my
2.1.0 :010"> double
2.1.0 :011"> quoted
2.1.0 :012"> multiline
2.1.0 :013"> string
2.1.0 :014"> }
 => "\nmy\ndouble\nquoted\nmultiline\nstring\n"
```

a bit more info http://simpleror.wordpress.com/2009/03/15/q-q-w-w-x-r-s/